# Calculation of $\sum_{i=1}^{k} \binom{n}{i}$

Tags: combinatorics

I would like to know if there is a way to calculate $\sum_{i=1}^{k} \binom{n}{i}$ in closed form. I know that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \binom{n}{i} = 2^n$ so we could say

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{k} \binom{n}{i} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \binom{n}{i} - \sum_{i=k+1}^{n} \binom{n}{i}
$$

but there is still the second sum for calculation, so nothing changes. Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: It is not true that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \binom{n}{i} = 2^n$. What is true: $\sum_{i=0}^{n} \binom{n}{i} = 2^n$ or if you prefer $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \binom{n}{i} = 2^n-1$.

Comment: You cannot explicit more the partial sum.

Comment: It can be expressed as a hypergeometric function; specifically, a regularized incomplete beta function.